# Unable to install the thrift compiler while running the command "brew install thrift@0.12"

Tags: homebrew, thrift

Unable to install the thrift compiler while running the command "brew install thrift@0.12"
I get the below error:

````
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.```
Can someone suggest an alternative or a fix?
````